# Bigquery Data got deleted automatically

Tags: google-bigquery

Google Analytics data got stored in 2 tables

1. events_{{Date}}
2. events_intraday_{{Date}}
   We need t-1 data always and somedays google moves data from events_intraday_ to the events table and somedays it won't move.
   So I created a clone of the events table as new_{{date}} and I wrote a cron to copy events_intraday_{{Date}} one day earlier data to new_{{date}}. It is working fine.
   The issue is that without any intervention the newly added data to new_{{date}} got deleted automatically.

Comment: Hello. Can you check the table expiration for the `new_{{date}}` table? Since you observed that the data got deleted automatically, it could be because of the table expiration settings. Is the `new_{{date}}` table a partitioned table?

Comment: Thank you @KabilanMohanraj
Looks like the issue was expiration settings on the table

Comment: Thank you at @Debashish for confirming. I will post the solution as an answer shortly. Can you please accept it?

Comment: Sure will do so

Comment: Hello @Debashish! I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you observed that the data got deleted automatically, it could be because of the table expiration settings. If a table's expiration is reached, the table itself will be dropped. If the table is partitioned, the respective partitions that have reached the expiration duration will be dropped.

Comment: Is it possible to recover those tables?

Comment: This is too late to answer. But, for future fellows, you can restore tables within time travel window specified for the dataset as explained here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables?cloudshell=false#bq_5